# how can i create or set device lock in Background when NSLocalnotification is displayed

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4

I have created an alarm application. I use `UILocalNotification` to display notifications in the background. My notification message is displayed by notification `AlertBody`.

But, I don't know how to display `Slider` lock according to `AlertBody`.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more, you question as is is really hard to understand.

Comment: i create alaram application ...i use UILocalNotification for display notification in background.!! my notification message is display by notification AlertBody...bt if i want to display Slider lock according to AlertBody then how can i do....plZ give me answer :)

Comment: I'm still not a 100% sure on what you want, your english is really hard to follow. But see my answer, since what you want probably isen't possible.

Comment: thanks frnd .. You are trying to help me :)

Comment: thanks frnd .. You are trying to help me :)  i tell you that when my UIlocalNotification is Display on BackGround at specified time (By fireDate)..generally Alert message is display but i want to display Slider Lock  according to Alert message :) thaks :)

Comment: No that can not be done, the systems (iOS) handle the notification, You can't change that, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refere document of `UILocalNotification` following are some link for `UILocalNotification` ...generally you can not set `Slider Lock` instad of `AlertBody` 
message.

Below describe some Links.

[.pdf file for NSLocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/UILocalNotification_Class.pdf)

[link1](http://www.picksourcecode.com/ps/ct/161237.php)

[link2](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/)

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the way iOS handles notifications. The user can set the way a notification is displayed in the settings app.